# Is there a way to choose Emmet suggestion in VSCode without expanding

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I try now to use Emmet, but I have a problem, so emmet gives several suggestions, I want now choose one suggestion from the list without expanding, so I can for example still add an ID with emmet.

For better understanding I give an example. So I want to create in HTML a checkbox with an specific ID directly with emmet. The word checkbox is quite long so i want to choose it directly from the suggestions, so the suggested abbreviation get into my line without expanding.

Here some pictures: [Emmet with suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HH3I.png) so now what is happening when I click enter Emmet expands the suggestion like in this image: [Emmet expanded the suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y4EP.png) But I actually want to happen this: [Emmet suggestion chosen but not expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31sGU.png) So I can write the Hash and add an ID of my choice
Like a similar system that you also have when searching, for example at google you can select a suggested search term but edit it further and not directly start the search.
I hope I could describe my problem clearly, so now my question is, is there a way to choose the emmet abbreviation without expanding?
Thanks

Comment: @topsail Yes I am, you cant see it on the screenshots, but here on this screenshot is clearly standing Emmet Abbreviation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lz2X.png

Comment: that are CompletionItem-s and Emmet has set a command to fill in a snippet, maybe there is an Emmet setting that replaces it with the suggested text, if not you can create a feature issue at the VSC  repo

Comment: but at what time do you want the expression to be expanded with a TAB or Enter

Comment: For me its not so important what key I have to press to expand the snippet, I just want that it is not expanding, just complete the snippet so I can add more to the snippet like an ID. But I found nothing in the internet or in the settings (even to I , so I guess there is not such a thing.

Comment: I raised a feature-request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/195111. feel free to join in on the design discussion.